# Cannot receive JSON exception message/content type on remote requests

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a ASP.NET MVC3 application, which uses JSON to comunicate with a Flash UI.

I´m use an ActionFilterAttribute to handle JSON exceptions (from Handle JSON Exceptions Gracefully in ASP.NET MVC 2: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=496):

```
public class HandleJsonExceptionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.Exception != null)
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
            filterContext.Result = new JsonResult()
            {
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
                Data = new
                {
                    filterContext.Exception.Message,
                }
            };
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

It´s works ok when executes on localhost, details from fiddler:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 3.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 11 Apr 2011 19:05:21 GMT
Content-Length: 34
```

{"Message":"No está autenticado"}

But, when executed from remote clients, on the LAN for example, I get the response in "Content-Type: text/html" instead "Content-Type: application/json;" and the content is a standard html error page:

500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 3.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 11 Apr 2011 19:07:53 GMT
Content-Length: 1208
```

What or where I need to configure something to get the JSON response on remote requests?

I need the flash UI receive a http 500 error, but with the json message instead the html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the article the javascript only seems to be wire up for local requests.
What you need is to be using jsonp. (json with padding). This will allow you to do proper cross domain request returning a json object.

Further info can be found [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem, I solved with this code in web.config

```
<httpErrors existingResponse="PassTrough"></httpErrors>
```